# A Ruby class to compare the characters in two strings

Tags: ruby, string, function, class, compare

I'm trying to complete an exercism.io test file which compares two strings and adds one to a counter each time there is a difference between the two strings. I've written my class, but for some reason it won't run in terminal. I've compared my code with several examples of syntax online and don't see why it won't run. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my class:

```
class Hamming
    def compute(str1, str2)
        distance = 0
        length = str1.length
        for i in 0..length
            if str1[i] != str2[i] then
                distance++
            end
        end
    return distance
    end
end
```

And here's a relevant bit of test file:

```
class HammingTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_identical_strands
    assert_equal 0, Hamming.compute('A', 'A')
  end
end
```

Lastly, here's the error I'm getting:

```
hamming_test.rb:4:in `require_relative': /Users/Jack/exercism/ruby/hamming/hamming.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end (SyntaxError)
/Users/Jack/exercism/ruby/hamming/hamming.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
    from hamming_test.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Tried that. No dice!

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need `then` after condition in `if` statement.
2. Use two spaces instead of four for indentation in Ruby.
3. (Direct cause of your error) there's no `++` operator in Ruby. You should have

   ```
   distance += 1
   ```

Comment: When in lists, you indent code with 8 spaces, not 4 :)

Comment: That solved it! Thank you, I feel silly. If only error messages weren't so damn cryptic!

Comment: @Jac7k: your code will still fail with "NoMethodError: undefined method ‘compute’ for Hamming:Class". This one is much easier to figure out.

Comment: @Jac7k only syntax error in Ruby are a little bit 'cryptic' in Ruby in my opinion. Runtime errors are much more self-explanatory.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev definition should be 'self.compute' rather than 'compute'. Caught that one by comparing it to my previous test assignment. Thanks guys!